# Quartz application scoped JNDI EJB Lookups

Tags: jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, jndi, lookup

I am working with Quartz 2.1.5 as a Clusterable Scheduler in a Java EE 7 Environment (Wildfly).
After a Quartz job is started the job needs to access Java EE session beans.
My software is a bit older (no dependency injection was available ) so the job uses jndi lookups to get the session beans.
as a jndi lookup I use the portable JNDI Syntax.

java:app[/module name]/enterprise bean name[/interface name]

or

java:global[/application name]/module name/enterprise bean name[/interface name]

I am currently fighting the problem that Quartz does not find the Beans using the application scoped jndi name (java:app)
It only can find the session bean using the global jndi variant.
For some purposes not explained here I need the application scoped variant to work.
My Java EE application is all deployed within a single EAR.

Any ideas why only the global JNDI works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own [org.quartz.spi.ThreadExecutor](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/spi/ThreadExecutor.html) and/or [org.quartz.spi.ThreadPool](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/spi/ThreadPool.html) classes that make use of the [javax.enterprise.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/package-summary.html) package for their implementation.

The [JSR 236: Concurrency Utilities for JavaTM](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236) will be a useful reference.